# Is it possible to set the position of an Attachment in a MailItem?

Tags: c#, com, outlook-2007

I'm trying to position an attachment in an RTF mail of Outlook 2007 created via COM:

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
// ...
private static void CreateMailWithAttachment()
{
    Outlook.Application ol = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem) ol.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
    mail.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatRichText;
    mail.Subject = "Important e-mail";
    mail.Body = "1234567890 1234567890 1234567890";
    mail.Attachments.Add(@"c:\myfile.txt", Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, 2);
    mail.Display();
}
```

The [documentation of `Attachments.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.attachments.add%28v=office.12%29.aspx) does not explicitly say what happens when a value between 2 and the length of the mail is used:

> This parameter applies only to e-mail messages using Microsoft Outlook Rich Text format: it is the position where the attachment should be placed within the body text of the message. A value of 1 for the Position parameter specifies that the attachment should be positioned at the beginning of the message body. A value 'n' greater than the number of characters in the body of the e-mail item specifies that the attachment should be placed at the end. A value of 0 makes the attachment hidden.

I'm seeing the following behavior:

- `0`: Works as described, attachment is hidden.
- `1`: Does not work as described, attachment is at the end of the body.
- `> 1`: Attachment is at the end of the body.

It's the same when starting Outlook with command line arguments `/noextensions` or `/safe`.

Is it possible to position an attachment in the middle of a mail? Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried to use the RTFBody property instead of Body?

Comment: @SimonMourier: RTFBody is not available in Office 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's [KB967677](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967677/en-us), although I'm pretty sure the patch is installed. It works perfectly with Outlook 2003.

Sorry for bothering.